# FromForm attribute for binding doesn't work on .NET CORE API

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to also support formdata in my controllers but it seems to be not working.

This is my controller action;

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("create_foo_from_form")]
public ActionResult<Foo> GetFooFORM([FromForm] Bar requestForm)
{
    var abc = ExecuteAction(() =>
    {
        return _fooService.AddFoo(requestForm);
    });
    return abc.Result;
}
```

My `Bar` Object is;

```
public class Bar
{
    ...
    public string BarNo { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But whenever I try to send `FormData` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` data to the api using `Postman` with the value `BarNo=123456` the controller action doesn't catch on that. And the `requestForm` object's `BarNo` attribute always is `null`.
Also `[FromBody]` works just fine if I send `Json` `Raw Data` from Postman.

Picture:
[image: pic]

Comment: If it didn't work, thousands of developers would have complained years ago. Have you actually tried posting from a form? If that works, the problem is how you create the request in POSTMAN. BTW that `ExecuteAction` and `abc.Result` are extremely suspicious. If that `ExecuteAction` returns a Task. you're effectively blocking the request thread while waiting for a second thread to do the work. HTTP requests are always served by separate background threads so there's no point in starting *another* background thread. This uses two threads to do a single thread's work. Use async/await at least.

Comment: Even then, `await` should be used for really asynchronous work. Especially when they don't match the code. You already posted the controller action's code so what's the point of hiding the names? Are you using *different* actions and classes that may not match what you already posted?

Comment: Don't post images. Images can't be copied, compiled, executed or googled.

Comment: It is for supplying try-catch mechanism. Instead of writing that in every conrtoller action or service we write it in a method. There's no async job going on in there.And as you can see it hasn't really went inside the `ExecuteAction`.

Comment: I can't see anything. Images don't compile and the images you posted don't seem to match the code. If it's not asynchronous, what's the point of `.Result`? Posting works. It's not just mj313's answer that proves this, it's thousands of .NET Core developers. Which means the problem is in the code, perhaps a mismatched DTO.

Comment: If you have to deduct, the image is pointless. Create a new, minimal project that contains only the relevant classes and try with *that*. Provide *test code* that matches the actual code. If you post images from POSTMAN make sure they use actual code. I suspect you'll find the bug immediately once you create a separate project

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I updated my issue with a picture. Everything seems to be the same but I get an error :/

Comment: Do you have any Attribute on the property? Is it Ok with other model properties, maybe you can have a new model to try.

Comment: @oividiosCaeremos the picture doesn't show anything. This answer proves that what you claim can't be reproduced. There's a problem in the code you ommited

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You don't need my `service` to reproduce this issue. Because the issue simply doesn't happen after a return. It happens when the action is called. There's no problem in the code. You can simply get rid of the `ExecuteAction` method and return a response. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: @oividiosCaeremos almost all of your previous questions have no answers. The one that does, also has a very long comment discussion trying to find out what the problem is. The problem isn't the answerers. Please read [How to Write a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)